# white lines appear in buffer after resizing frame

Tags: emacs

I get ugly white lines in my emacs buffers after I run a ":height" resize command in my init.el file (see screenshot and command below).  What I am doing wrong?

Note I use OSX, and the white lines disappear if I manually resize the frame with the mouse.

Note 2:  the white lines don't appear if I set face height attribute = 120 (which happens to be the default setting).  Also the white lines do not appear if I start up emacs in full screen mode with:

```
(setq initial-frame-alist
    '((fullscreen . maximized) (fullscreen-restore . fullheight)))
```

command:

```
(setq initial-frame-alist '((top . 25) (left . 25) (width . 250) (height . 77)))
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 130)
```

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Does `C-l` help?

Comment: C-l (recenter-top-bottom) is not helping

Comment: Try `(defun foo () (interactive) (let ((recenter-redisplay t)) (recenter)))`

Comment: The lines disappear but new ones come back as soon as I scroll up and down with the mouse (also with M-{ M-}).